# How to do validation on button on click and oneclick using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery's `one()` method to create a table header and on click for row insertion. Before the button click event I need to do some validation. I tried some methods but they are not working.

```
$("#btnOkIssue").one('click', function () { 
    var $head = $("#table_issue_entry");
    var tableHead=jQuery('<thead><tr><th class="col-xs-2">Indent Date</th><th class="col-xs-1">Indent No</th><th class="col-xs-2">Indent Remarks</th><th class="col-xs-2">Ingredient Name</th><th class="col-xs-1">Quantity</th><th class="col-xs-1">Stock</th><th class="col-xs-1">Issue Quantity</th><th class="col-xs-2">Issue Remarks</th></tr></thead>');
    $head.prepend(tableHead);

    var but = jQuery('<span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_indent" onclick="indent_save()">Save</button></span>');                                     
    $head.append(but);
});

$('#btnOkIssue').on('click',function (e){
    issue_view();     //  for row insertion
});

function issueValidation(){
    var y = document.forms["issue_head"]["issue_dept"].value;
    if (y == 'Please Select') {
        $.toaster({ 
            priority: 'info', 
            title: 'Info', 
            message: 'Please select valid department name' 
        });
    } else {
        // ????????????????????
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return the boolean value to check.

```
function is_valid(){

   var y = document.forms["issue_head"]["issue_dept"].value;

         if(y == 'Please Select')
    {
        $.toaster({ priority : 'info', title : 'Info', message : 'Please select valid department name' });
        return false;
    }

   else{
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: How will these boolean values invoke onclick and onclick event?

Comment: Why not call this method on onclick and onblur methods?